# UICollectionView is not reloading search results even with reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I can get the search feature to filter out the results but it won't display those searched results on the iPhone emulator. It displays the results on the iPhone I have (iPhone 5) but not on the emulator. I don't know why they collection view is not updating while I type. The items in the array are being displayed because the I first navigate to that screen I can see them.

[image: my screenshot]

```
import UIKit



class BrowseViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {




    @IBOutlet weak var testCollectionView: UICollectionView!



    var Array = [Product]()
    var currentArray = [Product]() //update table





    private func setUpAnimals() {

        Array.append(Product(name: "Cheetos", price: "3.99", image:"1"))
        Array.append(Product(name: "Coca Cola", price: "2.29", image:"2"))
        Array.append(Product(name: "Red Bull", price: "3.79", image:"3"))
        Array.append(Product(name: "Doritos", price: "1.99", image:"4"))
        Array.append(Product(name: "Lays Barbecue", price: "1.89", image:"5"))
        Array.append(Product(name: "Skittles", price: "1.49", image:"6"))
        Array.append(Product(name: "Cheez It", price: "1.29", image:"7"))
        Array.append(Product(name: "Pringles", price: "3.49", image:"8"))
        Array.append(Product(name: "Lays", price: "1.89", image:"9"))
        Array.append(Product(name: "Fritos", price: "3.99", image:"10"))


        currentArray = Array

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setUpAnimals()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        let itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3 - 3

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 30, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize (width: itemSize, height: itemSize)

        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 3

        testCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout



    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }








    // Number of views in the collection view

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.currentArray.count
    }



    //Populating the viewsc

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // Shows Image
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionViewCell
        cell.testImageView.image = UIImage(named: currentArray[indexPath.row].image + ".jpg")
        cell.titleLabel.text = (self.currentArray[indexPath.row].name)
        cell.priceLabel.text = ("$" + self.currentArray[indexPath.row].price)

        return cell
    }






    // Search Bar
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        currentArray = Array.filter({ Product -> Bool in
            switch searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex {
            case 0:
                if searchText.isEmpty { return true }
                return Product.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            default:
                return false
            }
        })
        //self.testCollectionView.reloadData()
       DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.testCollectionView.reloadData()
        }


    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        switch selectedScope {
        case 0:
            currentArray = Array

        default:
            break
        }
           DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                     self?.testCollectionView.reloadData()
                 }

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddToCartViewController") as? AddToCartViewController
        VC?.image = UIImage(named: currentArray[indexPath.row].image + ".jpg")!
        VC?.name = (self.currentArray[indexPath.row].name)
        VC?.price = (self.currentArray[indexPath.row].price)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC!, animated: true)

    }



}
```

Comment: Naming a property `Array` is quite confusing as that is the name of the Swift foundation type. Properties should start with a lower case letter (`array`) but that also isn't a very descriptive property name.  Similarly the parameter to your filter block should be `product`.  There is no need for the async dispatch in this code since you will already be on the main queue. Have you used debugging breakpoints to see what is happening?

Comment: Yes, and it is properly accessing the array but I'm not sure if it is properly filtering it out. The filter was working when I was running it on swift 3 but I just upgraded it to swim 5 and I am getting this issue. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Where are you setting the search bar's delegate? I don't see it happening in the code sample you posted. If the delegate isn't set the `textDidChange` won't fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you didn't set a delegate so the search bar callback methods aren't called!

If you use SearchController, you need to add this line to `viewDidLoad`

```
navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
```

Otherwise, set searchBar delegate to it

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```

Note: You should change `Array` name to a more descriptive name following Camel Case naming convention like `filteredArray`